# Android - Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1)

Tags: android, mobilepush-android

Created new firebase project for my app and I'm considering using a new FCM V1 API, but in SalesForce MobilePush setup it requires Server Key to start sending push notifications.

Question is where i can find Server key for V1? It only has Service account, but legacy FCM has server key accessible in Firebase.

[image: Firebase console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MobilePush `requires` the **Legacy Server Key** (ref. https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/provisioning/google.html). Follow the links/prompts on Firebase's admin console to get to the correct key.