# Firebase Cloud Messaging API (Legacy) scheduled to be decommissioned in June, 2024

Tags: mobilepush, sfdcmobilesdk-android, mobilepush-android

I use SFMC Android SDK for the apps in my company and we have received a notification from Firebase stating that the Legacy HTTP protocol will be decommissioned soon. When looking through the documentation, I noticed that even for new implementations, SFMC recommends we use this legacy approach. This got me worried.

As I've checked in this question: [Android - Firebase Cloud Messaging API (V1)](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/386386/android-firebase-cloud-messaging-api-v1) - SFMC uses the Legacy HTTP protocol by design and it will stop working in June, 2024.

Do we have any plans for updating this requirement? If we don't have an update to use the V1 Cloud Messaging API, all apps that use SFMC Android SDK **will stop working** from my understanding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Contact Salesforce through your account representative. They can align you with the internal work items already underway.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a `road map` type of question resolvable through the Account Executive and/or Support.

Comment: OK @BillMote I'm gonna close this and try the internal support

Comment: I don't believe it should be deleted though since more developers could see it and use your answer as the correct procedure to solve it

Comment: Starting with support or the account executive should _always_ be your first course of action.